# Adding two unequally sized numpy arrays (length n and m) to produce a n * m array without using for loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to vectorise a couple of simple calculations. I have two arrays:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])
B = np.array([1,2])
```

I want to compute an array C, which is calculated as follows:

```
C = []
for i in A:
  for j in B:
     C.append(i+j)

C = np.array(C)
```

such that

```
C = array([2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6])
```

In reality the arrays are quite large and these for loops take quite a while. Is there a way to vectorise these calculations?

Comment: In performance or pythonic way, you are asking, If pythonic, you can use list comprehension `np.array([i + j for i in A for j in B])`

Comment: Performance. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
In [4]: (A[:, None] + B).reshape(-1)
Out[4]: array([2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6])
```

Or `outer`:

```
In [7]: np.add.outer(A, B).reshape(-1)
Out[7]: array([2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Shouldn't we encourage using `np.newaxis` instead on `None`? It's more explicit.

Comment: @FHTMitchell That's opinion based. `None` is more idiomatic once one gets familiar with NumPy. As a placeholder, `np.newaxis` is too long

Comment: +1 for `np.newaxis`, way more self explanatory than `None`... as much as  I love `numpy` I too often find myself writing clever and unmaintainable code

Comment: `np.newaxis` is an alias for `None`, which makes it debatable whether using it is any clearer.